# Why could I do a right shift by two bits to access to the GPIO at the odroid board?

Tags: c, arm, gpio, odroid

[Here](http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:xu3_gpio_register) is an example of a C source code to deal with the GPIO at the odroid XU3 board. My question is what is the `>> 2` intended for in the constructions like this one:

```
*(gpio + (0x0c24 >> 2)) |= (1 << 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

- `gpio` is a `uint32_t` pointer.
- The address `0x24` is given on a byte wise basis.
- When we add 1 to 32 bit pointer, the address jumps 4 locations. So, we have to add the `address/4` to get to the correct position. (`>>2` is hte same as dividing by 4)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the variable is declared like so:

```
static volatile uint32_t *gpio;
```

So it's a pointer to 32-bit unsigned integers. This means that if we add `1` in the code to the pointer, the *actual address referenced* will be 4 bytes later than before. This is how pointer arithmetic works in C.

So, to use the byte offset `0xc24` from the base, that offset needs to be scaled down by four, which is what a shift right of two bits does.

It could just as well be written:

```
*(gpio + 0xc24 / 4) |= (1 << 2);
```

But often you see shifts used for powers of two. Modern compilers do this optimization easily, you won't see a division in the code for this (or even a shift, since the term can be computed compile-time).

Comment: Thank you. I loosed sight of the `uint32_t` in the `gpio`'s declaration. By the way: may I use the `uint8_t` here? I am newbie for ARM. As far as I know at the ARM addressing of the words is more optimal.